# How to create uploads folder in angular 2 app?

Tags: node.js, angular

I am building an app using angular2 and I want to keep a folder named as 'uploads' at the root of my application. However since in angular the current root is 'src' it does not let me access images inside the uploads folder.

If I try to keep 'uploads' directory inside the src folder then everytime I upload a file to it, it rebuilds the application and refreshes the page. I would want to keep it in suchaway that angular cli doesnt refresh the application in case file upload happens.

I want to access the url like : http://localhost:4200/uploads/xyz.jpg in angular2 app

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The angular app is a front-end app. It is not meant to be used as file storage. The file storage should be done by a back-end app that will serve the uploaded files to the front-end app.

### Using your Front-end

Angular-cli does not compile any folder outside app or assets, so, you need to place the folder inside app or assets.
To access directly, place inside `assets` and access like `localhost:4200/assets/uploads/xyz.jpg`.

Remember that you need to be careful because if you use a git versioning system, when you make a pull in your production env, every file uploaded inside `assets/uploads` will be overwritten by the new version.

### Using your Back-end

Put the upload file outside the angular app so when you build or update the angular app nothing will be lost. And use a back-end to serve the files.

You should place the upload folder outside the angular app and serve it using your nodeJs app. Use the static feature of expressJs to serve your file in some endpoint like localhost/uploads/xyz.jpg (if your nodejs is in localhost). So, you don't touch the angular-

Comment: I understand that however if I try to access it like http://localhost:4200/uploads/xyz.jpg . It does not work

Comment: That is because :4200 is the port used by angular-cli to serve the FRONT-END app. Angular-cli does not compile any folder outside app or assets, so, you need to place the folder inside app or assets. To access directly, place inside `assets` and access like `localhost:4200/assets/uploads/xyz.jpg`

Comment: I did try to do that. now what happens is... i have node js at the back end which uploads the files. Once the file goes from angular2 to nodejs and successfully uploaded then since modification has happend in the assets folder, the angularcli automatically starts recompiling. I dont want it to recomplie the app just because an image was uploaded in the assets folder..

Comment: As I said, Angular-cli is your front-end app. You should place the upload folder outside the angular app and serve it using your nodeJs app. Use the static feature of `expressJs` to serve your file in some endpoint like `localhost/uploads/xyz.jpg` (if your nodejs is in `localhost`). So, you don't touch the angular-cli folder.

Comment: localhost would run if i have php set up in my pc. I am going to upload the app to heroku. in that case 'www.xyz.com/uploads/xyz.jpg'.. would it run?? can it fetch files?